# How not rebuild react native app before running e2e tests?

Tags: react-native, mocking, e2e-testing, stubbing, detox

I am using detox for testing my RN application

I have a stub for Facebook login in tests like this:

```
// js/actions/login.e2e.js

function fbAuth() {
  console.log('stubbed auth with Facebook');
}

module.exports = { fbAuth };
```

When I build my app with `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js react-native run-android` and then run the tests `detox test -c android.emu.debug` it uses file with the stub

When I build my app with `react-native run-android` and then run the tests it uses non-stub version (real login with Facebook)

My detox config looks as follows

```
 "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "android.emu.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
        "build": "cd android && RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Android_Accelerated_Nougat"
      }
    }
  }
```

The question is: how can I configure detox to use `*e2e.js` files in tests without running `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js react-native run-android` before starting the tests?

I've tried

`RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration android.emu.debug --grep :ios: --invert`

`RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js detox test -c android.emu.debug`

but it didn't help

**UPDATE:**

Actually `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js react-native run-android` doesn't help: I need to stop my Metro process and run `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js react-native run-android` to force RN to use `e2e.js` files in the test bundle